# Put together arrays in dev-c++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I have homework that asks to count how many different mushrooms were collected in several days, several times in month and arrange them in ascending order by days

**Meanings:**

11 - how many lines are ( for **for** function)

*First number* - days when mushrooms were collected

*three other numbers* - different types of mushrooms ( **B**,**R**, and **L**)

**Data Example:**

11

2 8 4 0

3 1 0 9

1 2 3 4

5 4 14 2

2 4 4 4

3 0 0 0

15 25 45 13

28 13 13 13

16 2 0 2

16 5 15 25

3 4 44 444

*repetitive days numbers indicate that mushrooms were collected several times that day

I've already arrange them in order but cant merge arrays (mushrooms)

*(n) represents number 11

```
void count (int D[], int B[], int R[], int L[], int n){
    for ( int i=0; i<n;i++){
        for ( int j=i+1; j<n;j++){
            if ( D[i]==D[j]  && B[i] > B[j] && R[i] > R[j] && L[i] > L[j] ) {
                ; B[i]+=B[j];R[i]+=R[j];L[i]+=L[j];
            } 
            if ( D[i] > D[j] ){
            swap(D[i],D[j]);swap(B[i],B[j]);swap(R[i],R[j]);swap(L[i],L[j]);  
            } 
            
        }
    }
}
```

> what i *have* to get :
>
> 1 2 3 4
>
> 2 12 8 4
>
> 3 5 44 453
>
> 5 4 14 2
>
> 15 25 45 13
>
> 16 7 15 27
>
> 28 13 13 13

What i *got*:

1    2    3    4

2    8    4    0

2    4    4    4

3    1    0    9

3    0    0    0

3    4   44  444

5    4   14    2

15   25   45   13

16    7   15   27

16    2    0    2

28   13   13   13

Answer (score 0):

Well. I understood that you have arrays that represents days, and types of mushrooms .

I have some steps that may help you to take some idea:

1) Use a struct to represent a record in order to reduce # of arrays.

2)Implement a function that sorts an array of that struct by it's day attribute.

3)Implement a function that takes a sorted array (A1)(sorted by the above function), and in it declare an array of that struct and loop over the A1 and assign it's values in the another array if A1[i-1].day !=A1[i].day and if you find repetition just update it's last values ,and after you loops return the array declared in the function.

Hope these steps gives you a hint .